# How Can I write INNER Join query using Sequelize on Node.js

Tags: node.js, database, orm, sequelize.js, sequelize-auto

I have two tables. One is tblEmailAuditLog having columns Id, OrderId, Body, CommunicationType, CreatedOn, Reciever, WorkflowStatusId, IsSuccess another one is tblLookUp having column names as LU_LookUpValue and LU_LOOKUPID. I want to join the two tables based on the columns (CommunicationType and LU_LOOKUPID)

My inner join query looks as below:

`select Id, OrderId, Body, CommunicationType, CreatedOn, Reciever, WorkflowStatusId, IsSuccess, LU_LookUpValue from tblEmailAuditLog INNER JOIN tblLookUp on tblEmailAuditLog.CommunicationType = tblLookUp.LU_LOOKUPID;`

I am trying to write the above query using sequelize ORM.
I have tried the below things.

1.

```
    let auditLogs = await MediMarket.TblEmailAuditLog.findAll({
              include: [
                {
                  model: MediMarket.TblLookUp,
                  required: true,
                  where: { orderId: req.body.orderId },
                },
              ],
            });
    



2.
```

```
let auditLogs = MediMarket.TblEmailAuditLog.hasMany(
        MediMarket.TblLookUp,
        { foreignKey: "CommunicationType" }
      );

      MediMarket.TblLookUp.belongsTo(MediMarket.TblEmailAuditLog, {
        foreignKey: "LU_LOOKUPID",
      });

      MediMarket.TblEmailAuditLog.findAll({
        where: { orderId: req.body.orderId },
        include: [MediMarket.TblLookUp],
      });
```

But it is not giving the expected result.

Comment: Show what SQL you got in the first case

Comment: I get error TblLookUp is not associated to TblEmailAuditLog. So Do I need to associated table TblLookUp to TblEmailAuditLog ? Because both are different tables.

Comment: If you execute a query `TblEmailAuditLog.findAll` then you need an association from TblEmailAuditLog to all included models

Comment: I tried this but this is giving me error : "Cannot convert undefined or null to object"


let results = await TblEmailAuditLog.findAll({
        attributes: [
          "Id",
          "OrderId",
          "Body",
          "CommunicationType",
          "CreatedOn",
          "Reciever",
          "WorkflowStatus",
          "WorkflowStatusId",
          "IsSuccess",
        ],
        include: [
          {
            model: TblLookUp,
            attributes: ["LU_LookUpValue"],
          },
        ],
        where: { orderId: req.body.orderId },
      });

Comment: Check if `TblLookUp` is defined as well as `req.body.orderId`

Comment: This is the mapping I defined.

TblEmailAuditLog.hasOne(TblLookUp, { foreignKey: "LU_LookUpId" });
TblLookUp.belongsTo(TblEmailAuditLog, { foreignKey: "CommunicationType" });

Comment: ya TblLookUp and req.body.orderId both are defined .

Comment: Can you add a formatted version of this request and the full description and stack trace of the error to the post? It's hard to read them in the comments